# TypeScript.MSBuild Error: Failed to create URI from *.js & .map.js

Tags: typescript, msbuild, travis-ci, msbuild-task, kudu

I've added the TypeScript.MSBuild NuGet package to two separate projects.

(Tested just now with version 2.7.2.)

Locally, it runs fine. On Kudu, it builds fine. However, on travis-ci and Bitbucket's pipelines, I receive the following error for each .ts file:

```
CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig: 
    /home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v6.12.0/bin/node /home/travis/build/<user>/<project>/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.7.2/tools/tsc/tsc.js --project "/home/travis/build/<user>/<project>/Scripts/TypeScript/tsconfig.json" --listEmittedFiles

    /home/travis/build/<user>/<project>/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.7.2/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(444,5): error : Failed to create URI from '\home\travis\build\<user>\<project>\Scripts\TypeScript\App.js'. [/home/travis/build/<user>/<project>/<project>.csproj]
    /home/travis/build/<user>/<project>/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.7.2/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(444,5): error : Failed to create URI from '\home\travis\build\<user>\<project>\Scripts\TypeScript\App.js.map'. [/home/travis/build/<user>/<project>/<project>.csproj]
```

My `tsconfig.json` file is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Also, it is interesting to note that running the command locally gives correct results: (Note that I DID run `nvm use 6.12.0` to see if it was a node problem)

```
C:\Users\User\Projects\Project> node ./packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.7.2/tools/tsc/tsc.js --project "<Project>/Scripts/TypeScript/tsconfig.json" --listEmittedFiles
TSFILE: C:/Users/User/Projects/Project/Scripts/TypeScript/App.js
TSFILE: C:/Users/User/Projects/Project/Scripts/TypeScript/App.js.map
```

So my question is: How can I keep the TypeScript.MSBuild NuGet package and get it to work with my ci?

EDIT: 
I connected to the travis container via ssh and ran the msbuild command twice. The second time, it built fine. It seems the MSBuild task is trying to build an URI too soon, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by moving `tsconfig.json` to the root folder of the project.